# Non blocking в Web flux

Tags: java, spring, асинхронность

Какая разница между blocking и Non blocking, ведь в non blocking запросе должен ведь какой то поток прослушивать ответ от сервера.
Не понимаю эту идею, какая будет польза от web flux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сетевой уровень Web Flux обслуживает [Netty](https://netty.io/). Грубо говоря, только один поток асинхронно принимает и обслуживает соединения. При обслуживании, например, [10 000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) и более одновременных соединений экономия ресурсов сервера весьма существенная.

Да и сам стиль программирования, задаваемый фреймворком, позволяет писать производительные, масштабируемые, легко поддерживаемые и расширяемые web-сервисы, в том числе микросервисы, намного проще, чем с использованием Spring MVC.

Comment: 1. Получается он передает этому единственному потоку данные для запроса а так же callbackи на случай успеха и не успеха, как это делается в javascripte, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Если абстрагироваться от деталей, то да.

Comment: 2. Как стиль программирования помогает писать производительнее, кроме того что потоки используются более эффективно?
3. Как web flux помогает писать микросервисы? spring boot я так же могу писать микросервисы!

Comment: Читаю в нэте и смотрю примеры но не понимаю

Comment: 2. Это слишком общий вопрос. Вам придётся очень много прочитать, чтобы получить на него исчерпывающий ответ. Начать рекомендую с "[The Reactive Manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org/)" и "[The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/ru/)" 3. Spring Boot - это вообще из другой оперы. Это фреймворк для автоконфигурирования и запуска Spring-приложений, на стиль программирования он никак не влияет.

Comment: да, сложно ответить так же как и понять. Вопрос тогда такой в каких случаях рекомендуется использовать web flux?

Comment: При написании web-сервисов.

Comment: Вэб сервисы я могу и с голыми сервлетами писать

Comment: Можете. Можно даже на Ассемблере их писать. Но с Web Flux будет проще. И чем сложнее будет web-сервис, тем проще будет реализовать его именно на Web Flux.